# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in ajax with laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

**app.jss file**

```
$('#modal-save').on('click', function(){

    // geting the properties
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {body: $('#post-body').val(), postId: postId , _token: token}
    })

    // after done
    .done(function(msg) {
        $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
        $('#edit-modal').modal('hide')
    });
});
```

**my script in view code**

```
<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var url = '{{ route('edit') }}';
</script>
```

**Route file**

```
Route::post('/edit', [
    'uses'=>'PostController@postEditPost',
    'as'=>'edit'
]);
```

**My controller file**

```
public function postEditPost( Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    // checking auth user
    $post = Post::find($request['postId']);
    if(Auth::user != $post->user){
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // updating the post content
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $post->update();
    return response()->json(['new_body' => $post->body], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your'e sending an ajax request to the server, but dont accept it like so in the controller.
Try this:

```
    // updating the post content
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $post->update();

    if(request()->expectsJson()){
      return response()->json(['new_body' => $post->body], 200);
      }

     //here you can return to whereever you need it if its not ajax
    return redirect('/');
```

Comment: not working,, actually in my script tag  i am passing token  {{ Session::token() }} but in ajax it could not be found.. thats the problem

Comment: i just found the error because of if(Auth::user != $post->user){
            return redirect()->back();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, you must provide `CSRF` token with each `post, put, delete` request.

Add meta tag inside `head` tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then use it in you ajax request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

See [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: Thanks first.i sent _token in hidden input.. does it effect?.. and i also added this but does not work

Comment: in ajax calls token should be sent through the http header as `X-CSRF-TOKEN` so you should do `$.ajaxSetup` before any call

Comment: i sent token like this ..how can i get this in $.ajax setup...<input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token" >

Comment: error is because of if(Auth::user != $post->user){
            return redirect()->back();
        } in controller

Comment: change `var url = '{{ route('edit') }}';` to `var url = '{{ url('edit') }}';`

Comment: sir not working.. actually i found the error i think when i have removed this from my controller file ajax works but when i add  this then it does not work.... if(Auth::user != $post->user){ return redirect()->back(); }  ...any idea?